# How to add new array inside the existing array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I have existing array with like this

```
array:15 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "27"
    1 => "260"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▶]
  2 => array:2 [▶]
  3 => array:2 [▶]
  4 => array:2 [▶]
  5 => array:2 [▶]
  6 => array:2 [▶]
  7 => array:2 [▶]
  8 => array:2 [▶]
  9 => array:2 [▶]
  10 => array:2 [▶]
  11 => array:2 [▶]
  12 => array:2 [▶]
  13 => array:2 [▶]
  14 => array:2 [▶]
]
```

Now I want to put  (new array) following array starting with index 0 or starting from the first

```
   array:2 [▼
  0 => "Date"
  1 => "Views"
]
```

Please can anybody help me how I can add new array at the start of my existing array.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, are you looking for `array_unshift()`? see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

Comment: @KIKO Software As I have read the documentation  array_unshift()  adds element at first of the array but when I am using it is printing only total number of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array_push();

```
$arrayOld = array("Hello", "I", "am", "first","array");

$arrayNew = array("Hello", "I", "am", "second","array");

$arrayMergedArray = array_push($arrayOld,$arrayNew);
```